# Spark - Kudu predicate pushdown

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, spark-streaming-kafka, apache-kudu

I'm using kudu and spark streaming for a realtime dashboard, my problem is that when I'm joining the batch from spark streaming with kudu table it doesn't make a predicate pushdown on it and takes 2-3 seconds to fetch the entire table in spark and after that filter it.
It's any way to avoid this?

Thanks,

Alexandru

Answer (score -1):

1.Kudu is a Columnar storage engine,so you can select what column you need.It can decrease the data pulled from kudu.

2.kudu predicate pushdown support >,<,>=,<=,=,BETWEEN, or IN
maybe you can cache the data,after you filtering data from kudu.And predicate pushdown may  triggered.

Comment: Are you sure it does predicate pushdown on join ? I know that >,<,>=,<=,=,BETWEEN, or IN are only on where.